# before adding check if object already exists in a list

Tags: c#, list

I am working on win-form app that has .`net 2.0` as framework. I have a list of an class in which i would like to check if the object already exist before adding it in list. I know i can use `.Any` of linq to do this but it does not work in my situation. I can not use `.contains` since the object will not be same as it has lot of properties , so I am left with a unique property to check if it is already added,but it is not working Code:

```
bool alreadyExists = exceptionsList.Exists(item =>
       item.UserDetail == ObjException.UserDetail    
    && item.ExceptionType != ObjException.ExceptionType) ;
```

My class

```
public class AddException
    {
        public string  UserDetail{ get; set; }
        public string  Reason { get; set; }
        public Enumerations.ExceptionType ExceptionType { get; set; }

    }
    public class Enumerations
    {
        public enum ExceptionType
        {
            Members = 1,
            Senders =2
        }
    }
```

Iniial situation

```
AddException objException = new AddException
                {
                    Reason = "test",
                    UserDetail = "Ankur",
                    ExceptionType = 1
                };
```

this object is added in list.

Second time

```
AddException objException = new AddException
                {
                    Reason = "test 1234",
                    UserDetail = "Ankur",
                    ExceptionType = 1
                };
```

this should not be getting added in the list , but the `.Exist` check is failing and it is getting added in the list.

Any suggestions.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the not working part ? Also Exists would return true/false, so what do you think the comparison of `true != null` or `false !=null` would result in

Comment: What is the problem with `Any`?

Comment: if there is an object of ObjException with userDetail as "Ankur", If again i come with the a different object with userDetail as "Ankur" then the above statement should return false but it is true always.

Comment: SO there is no need to check for null it will be either true/false....

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: OP is using .NET 2.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Thanks. Missed that part.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I think he has issues using `.Any()` i guess he is compiling on 3.5 with the target framework as `2.0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Exists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfed8bca%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) returns already the `bool` and not an object, so your null check at the end doesn't work.

```
bool alreadyExists = exceptionsList.Exists(item =>
        item.UserDetail == ObjException.UserDetail
     && item.ExceptionType == ObjException.ExceptionType
);
```

The important part is, you  have to change

```
item.ExceptionType != ObjException.ExceptionType
```

to

```
item.ExceptionType == ObjException.ExceptionType
```

since you want to know if there are items which are equal by `UserDetail` and `ExceptionType`.

Also note that you should not initialize `Enums` with their int-value. So change

```
AddException objException = new AddException
{
    Reason = "test 1234",
    UserDetail = "Ankur",
    ExceptionType = 1
};
```

to

```
AddException objException = new AddException
{
    Reason = "test 1234",
    UserDetail = "Ankur",
    ExceptionType = Enumerations.ExceptionType.Members
};
```

(By the way, that should not even compile)

Comment: it was not initialized with int value , i have done that for the sake of understanding.

Comment: @ankur: It does only confuse if you add code that does not compile, especially because you've shown us the enum. However, i'm glad to hear that it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .Contains method but you need to implement Equal method for your object.

Check this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
bool alreadyExists = exceptionsList.Exists(item => item.UserDetail == ObjException.UserDetail && item.ExceptionType != ObjException.ExceptionType);
```

Exists returns bool